# On algebraic groups of dimension 1

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-geometry, abelian-groups, algebraic-groups

I am searching for a possible analogue of a result in algebraic groups in a non-commutative setting, so I am looking for different proofs of the following :

> Let $K$ be an algebraically closed field. A connected (affine) algebraic subgroup of $(K,+)^n$ having dimension $1$ is isomorphic to $(K,+)$.

**Any ideas for elementary proofs ?**

Comment: Just to get the setting right: Which definition of algebraic group do you use? Affine group scheme? And are these schemes considered as functors, or as locally ringed spaces?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft By algebraic subgroup of $(K,+)^n$, I mean the intersection of zeros of finitely many polynomials. Does that answer your question ?

Comment: As it is one-dimensional, it will be $(K,+)$ or $(K*, \times)$ or an elliptic curve. You can't get an elliptic curve, because a subvariety of the affine variety $(K,+)^n$ is not projective. So you just have to exclude that you get $K*$. But how would this be a subgroup?

Comment: @AriyanJavanpeykar My question would be then : can you give me an (several ?) elementary proof(s) that a one-dimensional connected algebraic group is isomorphic to either $(K,+)$ or $(K^\times,\times)$ :-)

Answer (score 1):

What you stated is technically wrong since for example one can take $\mathbb{G}_a\times \alpha_p$ over $\overline{\mathbb{F}_p}$. So, you probably want to assume that the subgroup is also reduced. If so, then see the following.

If you're curious about a not-so-elementary proof of the classification of smooth connected one-dimensional algebraic groups you can see the following two links (**NB:** full disclosure, this is my blog):

1. https://ayoucis.wordpress.com/2014/11/29/classifying-one-dimensional-algebraic-groups/
2. https://ayoucis.wordpress.com/2019/11/19/classifying-one-dimensional-groups-ii/

For a sketch of the idea of this proof you can see my explanation here: [Classification of the algebraic affine smooth group schemes of dimension 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3712588/classification-of-the-algebraic-affine-smooth-group-schemes-of-dimension-1/3794027#3794027).

The claim then follows, as Ariyan noted, since any subgroup of $\mathbb{G}_a^n$ must be unipotent and thus must be $\mathbb{G}_a$ by the above classification.

If one wants another proof, possibly not so elementary (but in a different way), proof one can see [Mil, Corollary 14.33] and [Mil, Corollary 14.53].

Comment: What is [Mil] in this post?