# Classification of the algebraic affine smooth group schemes of dimension 1

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, group-schemes

How to prove that all algebraic affine smooth group schemes of dimension 1 are the additive group and the multiplicative one ?

Comment: See Boris Weisfeiler's paper  [here](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwi-mLex9fTpAhX1lFwKHeUGCtQQFjABegQIAxAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fboris.weisfeiler.com%2Fpapers%2F1980-jalg-schemes.pdf&usg=AOvVaw34DuwWOkYgf6t6lsTsTtbA).

Comment: I'll have a look at it, thanks !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the following might be of interest to the OP

> **Theorem:** Let $k$ be a perfect field and let $G$ be a finite type connected geometrically reduced group scheme over $k$. Then, $G$ is either an elliptic curve, $G$ is $\mathbb{G}_{a,k}$, or $G$ is a one-dimensional torus (i.e. $G_{\overline{k}}\cong \mathbb{G}_{m,\overline{k}}$). Moreover, one can explicitly parameterize all of these families.

For a proof of this one can see blost post [1] (DISCLAIMER: THIS IS MY BLOG--THIS IS ALSO A WELL-KNOWN RESULT WHICH IS NOT MINE).

Let me give the main ingredients for the case when one assumes that $G$ is affine and that $k$ is algebraically closed. One wants to show that $G$ is either $\mathbb{G}_{m,k}$ or $\mathbb{G}_{a,k}$.

**Step 1:** Note that if one lets $C$ denote the unique smooth projective compactification of $G$ then one has an injection

$$G(k)\hookrightarrow \mathrm{Aut}(C,Z)$$

where $Z=\{p_1,\ldots,p_m\}$ denotes the closed subscheme $C-G$ (given the reduced structure) and $\mathrm{Aut}(C,Z)$ denotes the group of automorphisms of $C$ as a $k$-scheme which preserves the subscheme $Z$.

**Step 2:** But, since $Z$ is finite and $G(k)$ is infinite it's easy to see that this implies that the group $\mathrm{Aut}(C,p_1,\ldots,p_m)$, the subgroup of $\mathrm{Aut}(G,Z)$ which fixes each $p_i$ pointwise, is also infinite.

**Step 3:** Now, since curves of genus at least $2$ have only finitely many automorphisms (e.g. see [2] for a nice proof by Dan Litt) we easily deduce that $g(C)\leqslant 1$.

**Step 4:** But, if $g(C)=1$ then for any choice of $p_i$ in $Z$ we see that $\mathrm{Aut}(C,p_i)$ is infinite. But, $\mathrm{Aut}(C,p_i)$ is just the group of automorphisms of elliptic curve $(C,p_i)$ which is finite (e.g. see [3, Theorem 10.1]). Thus, $g(C)=0$.

**Step 5:** Finally, since $\mathrm{Aut}(C,p_1,\ldots,p_m)$ is trivial for $m\geqslant 3$ we see that $m\in\{1,2\}$. This implies that $C=\mathbb{A}^1_k$ or $C=\mathbb{A}^1_k-\{0\}$ as schemes.

**Step 6:** The final step is to verify that the only group structures on the schemes $\mathbb{A}^1_k$ and $\mathbb{A}^1_k-\{0\}$, up to isomorphism are $\mathbb{G}_{a,k}$ and $\mathbb{G}_{m,k}$ respectively.

**References:**

[1] Youcis, Alex. *Classifying one dimensional groups (II)*. 2019. https://ayoucis.wordpress.com/2019/11/19/classifying-one-dimensional-groups-ii/

[2] Litt, Daniel. *Curves have finite automorphism groups*. [http://math.columbia.edu/~dlitt/briefnotes/notes/curve-automorphisms.pdf](http://math.columbia.edu/%7Edlitt/briefnotes/notes/curve-automorphisms.pdf)

[3] Silverman, J.H., 2009. *The arithmetic of elliptic curves* (Vol. 106). Springer Science & Business Media.